# error: expected ',' or '...' before 'Hash_Flag'

Tags: c++, struct, enums

I have a struct, defined as

```
typedef struct
{
  char* p_hash_start_position;
  size_t hash_capacity;

  //still a flag is needed since we might start from an empty container.
  Hash_Flag hash_status;

  char* p_start_position;
  char* p_current_position;
  size_t capacity;//tagged data capacity
} tagged_data_t;
```

And the enum is defined as

```
typedef enum Hash_Flag
{
    TD_HASH,
    TD_NO_HASH
} Hash_Flag;
```

Why do I get the following error?

```
error: expected ',' or '...' before 'Hash_Flag'
```

Comment: Please create a simple sequence of code that generates the error: you have two code sequences, and a syntax error with no clue what line it occurred on.  As an aside, `typedef struct { ... } tagged_data_t;` is C style, try `struct tagged_data_t { ... };`, and similarly for `Hash_Flag`.

Comment: The token `...` can legally appear only in a function declaration; it's used to declare a variadic functin (like `printf`). If the compiler is expecting to see a `...` token, then it must be processing a function declaration (unless it's badly confused, which is not impossible). You haven't shown us anything that looks like a function declaration. You need to update your question to show the actual code that produced the error. I should be able to copy-and-paste the code from your question into a file on my own computer and reproduce the error myself.

Comment: And why is the question tagged both C and C++? Which language are you using?

Comment: @KeithThompson I am using C++... Sorry for the mess

Comment: So, are you going to update the question? As it stands, there's no way we can diagnose the problem.

Comment: @lexie: There are no problems in what you posted so far (aside from the questionable idea of defining nameless class type and naming it through typedef in C++ code). Whatever is causing your error is rooted elsewhere. In many cases "unexplainable" errors are caused by macro definition conflicts. Do you by any chance have a macro `Hash_Flag` defined somewhere? Or, maybe, `hash_capacity` macro?

Comment: @lexie: Which line triggers the error?

Answer (score 5):

The definition of `enum Hash_Flag` should precede its use. Rearrange your code so that the structure definition follows `enum Hash_Flag`.

```
typedef enum Hash_Flag
{
    TD_HASH,
    TD_NO_HASH
} Hash_Flag;

typedef struct
{
  char* p_hash_start_position;
  size_t hash_capacity;

  //still a flag is needed since we might start from an empty container.
  Hash_Flag hash_status;

  char* p_start_position;
  char* p_current_position;
  size_t capacity;//tagged data capacity
} tagged_data_t;
```

---

If I write code like the one below, I can reproduce the issue you reported:

```
  1  typedef enum Hash_Flag
  2  {
  3      TD_HASH,
  4      TD_NO_HASH
  5  } Hash_Flag;
  6
  7  int foo(int x Hash_Flag) {}

$ g++ -c t.cc
t.cc:7: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'Hash_Flag'
```

You should go to the precise line of code reported by the compiler error, and see if you can see a missing comma between the function arguments.

If you do not spot an obvious missing comma in the line of code that the compiler reports the error on, the error may be due to an expanded macro. Try to get the compiler to expand the macros for you so you can observe the code after expansion. With `g++`, you would pass the `-E` flag to generate what the source code will expand into after all the macros have been expanded.

Comment: In my real code, I precede the definition of Hash_Flag before its use. So this should not be a problem.

Comment: You should post enough code that would actually generate the problem.